# Triggers not Activated by Yii Application

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

Hello everybody in StackOverflow, I'm a Fan of this site, has helped me out of countless pits. But this time I don't seem to find the answer here or anywhere else, my problem is this:

I'm developing a Yii Framework Application for handling of data within a database, keeping consistance and everything. Basically, I'm creating an interface for manipulting DB information. I'm using MySQL 5.0 (Scheduled update to 5.5) and InnoDB.

My development is coming to support an already-existing schema (I'll call it **main**), which has several design problems. We aim to replace the old schema with a new, rightly designed one (I'll call it **shadow**). But for the meantime, we are trying to implement the new schema as a shadow-schema of the main one, and keeping changes consistant via triggers.

All the important changes are made to the shadow schema, which reflects it to the main schema using triggers. Both schemas are hosted in the same server, and the triggers work great reflecting data changes from shadow to main whenever changes are made via command line client or using MySQL Workbench, but whenever I make changes using my Yii application to shadow data... the changes are only made to the shadow schema and not trigger-reflected to the main schema.

This is the **shadow.tbl_device** description and triggers DDL:

```
mysql> use shadow;
mysql> describe tbl_device;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| SerialNumber | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| State        | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | Recién Llegado    |                             |
| ProviderId   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| OwnerId      | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| ProfileId    | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| ChipId       | int(11)     | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| IMEI         | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ModelNumber  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| FirstUsed    | date        | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Brand        | varchar(45) | NO   | MUL | No Definida       |                             |
| Agreement    | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | No Establecido    |                             |
| LastUpdated  | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)

-- Trigger DDL Statements

USE `shadow`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `shadow`.`trg_device_after_insert_produce_location_and_register_device`
AFTER INSERT ON `shadow`.`tbl_device`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE NumCel VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL;
    INSERT INTO tbl_location(DeviceId) values (New.Id);
    IF New.ChipId IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT CONCAT(AreaCode,Phone) INTO NumCel FROM tbl_chip WHERE Id = New.ChipId;
    END IF;

    IF New.Brand = 'Navcel' THEN
        INSERT INTO navcel.detalle_aplicacion(apId, pdRadioId, adActivo) values (1,CAST(New.SerialNumber as UNSIGNED), 1);
    END IF;
    IF New.Brand = 'Calamp' Then
        INSERT INTO main.equipos(eqId,eqNumCel,shadowDeviceId) values (CONV(SUBSTRING(New.SerialNumber,-6),16,10),NumCel,New.Id);
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO main.equipos(eqId,eqNumCel,shadowDeviceId) values (CAST(New.SerialNumber as UNSIGNED),NumCel,New.Id);
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `shadow`.`trg_device_after_update_reflect_changes`
AFTER UPDATE ON `shadow`.`tbl_device`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE acuerdo TINYINT(4);
    DECLARE NumCel VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE eqIdToUpdate INT;
    IF New.LastUpdated <> Old.LastUpdated THEN
        /* UPDATING THE REFLECTION OF THIS DEVICE IN THE main SCHEMA */
        IF New.Agreement = 'Renta' THEN set acuerdo := 1;
            ELSEIF New.Agreement = 'Venta' THEN set acuerdo := 2;
            ELSEIF New.Agreement = 'Prestamo' THEN set acuerdo := 3;
            ELSE set acuerdo := 0;
        END IF;
        IF New.ChipId IS NULL THEN 
            SET NumCel = NULL;
        ELSE 
            Select CONCAT(AreaCode,Phone) INTO NumCel FROM tbl_chip WHERE Id = New.ChipId;
        END IF;
        UPDATE main.equipos SET 
            eqId := New.SerialNumber,
            eqInstalado := 1,
            eqAcuerdo := acuerdo,
            eqNumCel := NumCel
        WHERE shadowDeviceId = New.id;
    END IF;
END$$
```

The triggers in the DDL are the triggers intended to reflect changes to main, here is the **main.equipos** description (It uses no triggers,  currently):

```
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| eqId                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| shadowDeviceId        | int(11)          | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| eqNumCel              | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stId                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| TIPO_EQUIPOS_tpId     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqNombre              | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqNUI                 | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqModelo              | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqPlacas              | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqLatitud             | decimal(9,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqLongitud            | decimal(9,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqAltitud             | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqSatelite            | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqFechaActEq          | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqFechaActSer         | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqNivelGPRS           | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqIcono               | varchar(200)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqTiempoRep           | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqVersion             | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqLatDinGeo           | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqLonDinGeo           | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqTiempoGeo           | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqNumEconomico        | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqNumPedido           | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqVelocidad           | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqNumSerie            | varchar(45)      | YES  |     |         |       |
| EsGeocercaId          | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqPuntoCercano        | int(10)          | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| eqDistanciaCercano    | float            | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| eqIconoActual         | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| eqStatusDBS           | varchar(45)      | YES  |     |         |       |
| eqTieneDBS            | int(1)           | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| eqFechaDBS            | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqEnAlarma            | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| eqTipoMascara         | int(11)          | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| eqAdvComunicacion     | int(11)          | NO   |     | 120     |       |
| eqFallaComunicacion   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 300     |       |
| eqStComs              | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| eqCiudadCercana       | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqDistCiudadCercana   | float(11,0)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqUsaGeocercaDinamica | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| eqUcStatus            | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| eqOdometro            | float            | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| eqBoletin             | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| eqPaseSalida          | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| eqMedioTx             | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| eqDigInputs           | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| eqFechaActEqLocal     | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqLatitudCruda        | decimal(9,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqLongitudCruda       | decimal(9,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqVelocidadCruda      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqIconoWeb            | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | car     |       |
| eqUsaAnalogicas       | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| eqInstalado           | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| eqAcuerdo             | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| idEntidad             | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eqFallaECM            | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I think this table (referenced by the triggers), might be of relevance too:

```
mysql> describe shadow.tbl_chip;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ProviderId   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| OwnerId      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ChipState    | varchar(15) | NO   | MUL | Nuevo   |                |
| AreaCode     | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Phone        | varchar(7)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SerialNumber | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PIN          | varchar(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PUK          | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

So, basically... triggers fire whenever queries are sent via command-line/mysql-workbench, but not whenever they are sent via yii (which is hosted in the same server as the two DB schemas). I have seen the following:

As per [MySQL 5.0 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

> MySQL triggers are activated by SQL statements only.  They are not activated by changes in tables made by APIs that do  not transmit SQL statements to the MySQL Server; in particular,  they are not activated by updates made using the NDB API.

Any help or guideline is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Yii uses PDO to do insert/update statements, and inserts are reflected succesfully, updates still fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: try debugging it from console/workbench with same mysql user your yii app uses.

Yii still uses regular SQL statements, NOT api calls mentioned in the documentation you referenced.

go ahead and put in you config/main.php file

components/db section:

```
'enableParamLogging' => true
```

and components/log section:

```
    'log' => array(
        'class' => 'CLogRouter',
        'routes' => array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'trace,log',
                'categories' => 'system.db.CDbCommand',
                'logFile' => 'db.log',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

and then watch the sql commands getting executed in protected/runtime/db.log:

```
$ tail -f db.log
```

Also, are you sure you are not getting into endless loop here when updating main triggers updating shadow triggers updating main triggers updating shadow triggers.... ?

Comment: Debugging with the same user: it works from workbench, it works from command line cliend, it doesn't work from yii.

I'm not familiar with that unix (is it unix?) command, but I am checking db.log manually and found lots of select queries (corresponding to fk reference validation and such, everything goes smoothly)...

Comment: the only update line in the log is this:
`2012/10/29 23:46:38 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Executing SQL: UPDATE "tbl_device" SET "Id"=:yp0, "SerialNumber"=:yp1, "State"=:yp2, "ProviderId"=:yp3, "OwnerId"=:yp4, "ProfileId"=:yp5, "ChipId"=:yp6, "IMEI"=:yp7, "ModelNumber"=:yp8, "FirstUsed"=:yp9, "Brand"=:yp10, "Agreement"=:yp11, "LastUpdated"=:yp12 WHERE "tbl_device"."Id"=670. Bound with :yp0=670, :yp1='ADSF564ASD9F132CX1', :yp2='Recién Llegado', :yp3=12, :yp4=5, :yp5=NULL, :yp6=11, :yp7='123', :yp8='AD3F48C135', :yp9=NULL, :yp10='Skywave', :yp11='No Establecido', :yp12='2012-10-29 15:33:37'`

Comment: And there are no other important lines, just selects for validation and related record formatted display. The changes weren't reflected to the main schema, so I'm guessing `shadow.trg_device_after_update_reflect_changes` on `shadow.tbl_device` plainly didn't activate..

Comment: I have resolved the issue, seems I was having a validation misapproach, check out my own answer.. Thanks for teaching me implicitly how to config my log.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger I'm using `AFTER UPDATE` has a clause that somehow prevents changes from being made within the trigger (which actually is always fired),

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `shadow`.`trg_device_after_update_reflect_changes`
AFTER UPDATE ON `shadow`.`tbl_device`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE acuerdo TINYINT(4);
    DECLARE NumCel VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE eqIdToUpdate INT;
    IF New.LastUpdated <> Old.LastUpdated THEN
        ...
    END IF;
END$$
```

Seems like `New.LastUpdated <> Old.LastUpdated` is false whenever updating from Yii, but true whenever updating from CLI or WorkBench. Because on the Yii application I do not receive input for tbl_device.LastUpdated (I was expecting MySQL to do this job for me and now I feel kinda dumb for it, I can correct it using the `beforeSave()` method to update the Timestamp field I'm using to validate if changes were actually made to the record... )

Comment: Nice catch. Check out [CTimestampBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTimestampBehavior) on how to fill timestamp fields.